# What should be the first argument for repeat#set function if I want to use repeat.vim along with surround.vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

As per the site https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat, the procedure to enable repeat.vim is as follows:

`silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug\>MyWonderfulMap", v:count)`

But I don't understand the first argument of repeat#set function.  Can you please explain with an example?  If I want to configure repeat.vim along with surround.vim, what instruction should I include in .vimrc?  And how will that instruction change for unimpaired.vim?

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to do much in your vimrc if you want surround to get supported by `repeat`, if you check the codes of `surround`, the repeat functions were called there.

And for the explanation of the function, you will find it in the link you wrote in the question. read here:

https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat/blob/master/autoload/repeat.vim#L19

Comment: Should I paste the following verbatim in .vimrc?  silent! call repeat#setreg("\<Plug>MappingToRepeatCommand", v:register)

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have a wrong understanding of how repeat.vim works. You don't enable this by calling `repeat#set()` once (e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`); rather, the mapping itself must be modified to invoke `repeat#set()` after the mapping's normal work is done.

The way the repeat.vim plugin works is that each mapping has to tell it: Hi, I'm `<Plug>MyMapping`, and I just got executed. The repeat.vim plugin hooks into the `.` command, and if the last command came from such a mapping, it gets re-executed = repeated.

Therefore, repeat.vim support requires the cooperation of the plugin (which defines some mappings); either a plugin has it, or it hasn't (and then you have to ask the plugin's author to provide repeat.vim support, or use an external plugin like my [repeatableMapping plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4777) to modify the mappings after-the-fact.

But, as Kent has already stated, the *surround* plugin comes from the same author as repeat.vim, and it already has that support built-in.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Then I guess the following plugins doesn't require explicit repeat.vim: surround, speeddating, abolish, unimpaired and commentary.  Can you explain what "<Plug>" stand for?  Can you give an example?  I think it will be a great help if you can provide an example and explain each part of the mapping.

Comment: `<Plug>` is just a special prefix that will never come from the keyboard (i.e. typed by you directly), so it can be used for abstractions. Find more in Vim's extensive help at `:help <Plug>`